# Does heightForRowAtIndexPath get called before cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have certain code that I am refactoring and this came up

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy to tell by yourself, just add one NSLog in each of these methods... But yes, it's called before.